# Eclipse FileType add, Autocompletion not working

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse CDT (4.6.3) and having problems to get ".hpp"-files handled in same way like ".hxx" or ".h"-files.

I verified that the file-extension "*.hpp" is registered under

`Window->Preferences->C/C++->File Type`

The line containing the file-type "*.hpp" looks exactly like that one for "*.h" or "*.hxx"-files. I can't remove/overwrite it.

I also verified that the file-extension "*.hpp" is registered under

`Window->Preferences->General->Editor->File Associations`

and that the default Editor is the same as for "*.h" or "*.hxx" files.

Trouble starts as soon as adding a new header file using the "new" dialog. As soon as I choose ".hpp" as file extension I get the message

`File name is discouraged. File extension does not correspond to known header file types.`

I do not get this message when I try the file ending "*.hxx" or "*.h" for a C++-header-file.

Also autocompletion is not working for "*.hpp"-files - guess this is because of file-type "*.hpp" is not recognized as C++-header-file

Eclipse CDT also associates the "C-file"-icon for "*.hpp"-files instead of the expected "H-file"-icon.

- What point am I missing here? What .xml-files (plugin/properties/etc) to check for that issue?
- How can I add "*.hpp"-files to a list of "known header files"?

Comment: Autocompletion should start working as soon as you include this header file into some translation unit.

Comment: I do have some templates for creating classes, comments, header information etc. So typing "clas" pressing CTRL+space should open a list of auto-complete templates. Even this does not work as the file is not recognized as "known c++ header file"

Comment: Last night I've got some new insights. It seems not to be a problem within Eclipse CDT in general. I created a brand-new project and the problems described did not  occur. So I decided to delete all workspaces and removed all projects. I also tried to delete all eclipse-related settings within my target-project (.project, .cproject, .settings). I re-imported the target-project - This did not solve the problems described. So the problematic settings seems to be inside that target-project. How can I find them?

Comment: If you're able to share your project (or a modified version of your project with some code removed), I would suggest [filing a CDT bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT) and attaching a zip of your project.

Comment: I checked with my supervisor. I'm not allowed to publish parts of the code. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I finally found a workaround: I reimported the project using the standard "Existing Code as Makefile Project" and it seems that everything is working as expected. Normally for my kind of project I should use a different importer provided by an internal department.